# SUM and AVG of cells with SAME values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sum, average

I need somehow, to do `SUM(mnozstvi)` and `SUM(prostoje)` for cells with same dtzdanitpln + same podminky + same jmeno_uziv. Also after I group it by these 3 conditions, while having `SUM(mnozstvi)` I need to have AVG function for them in columns mnpracovniku, naklad and hdudrzbapracoviste

I searched for solutions to do SUM of cell with same id in another cell, but i get errors when i try to change my `group by`, for example if I try to remove the prac from Group by, i get this:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Column 'temptab.pracoviste' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 20 Column 'temptab.pracoviste' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Column
>   'temptab.pracoviste' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg
>   8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 Column 'temptab.pracoviste' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```sql
select
  count (temptab.idhdok) as pocet,
  temptab.ucet_obd,
  temptab.dtzdanitpln,
  substring (temptab.podminky_text, 4,2) as podminky,
  temptab.jmeno_uziv,
  temptab.textpozn2,
  count(temptab.pracoviste) as prac,
  temptab.mnpracovniku,
  SUM(temptab.hdmzda_naklad_smena) as naklad,
  temptab.hdodpis_naklad_smena,
  (select count(*) from qsdok where (cis_zbozi = 'PROSTOJ 03.3' or cis_zbozi = 'PROSTOJ 07' or cis_zbozi = 'PROSTOJ 08' or cis_zbozi = 'PROSTOJ 10') and qsdok.idhdok=temptab.idhdok) as prostoje,
    (select sum(qhdok_udr.hdccenaval2)
     from qhdok_udr
       left join typdok on typdok.idtypdok = qhdok_udr.idtypdok
     where
       typdok.typ_dok = 'UDR' and
       qhdok_udr.podminky_text != 'UDRMECH' and
       qhdok_udr.ucet_obd like '%2015.09%' and
       qhdok_udr.cis_zbozi_pracovisteadd like temptab.pracoviste
  ) as hdudrzbapracoviste,
  (select sum(qhdok_udr.hdccenaval2)
     from qhdok_udr
       left join typdok on typdok.idtypdok = qhdok_udr.idtypdok
     where
       typdok.typ_dok = 'UDR' and
       qhdok_udr.podminky_text != 'UDRMECH' and
       qhdok_udr.ucet_obd like '%2015.09%' and
       (qhdok_udr.cis_zbozi_pracovisteadd like 'M%')
  ) as hdudrzbacelkem,
  (select sum(qhdok_udr.hdccenaval2)
     from qhdok_udr
       left join typdok on typdok.idtypdok = qhdok_udr.idtypdok
     where
       typdok.typ_dok = 'UDR' and
       qhdok_udr.podminky_text = 'UDRMECH' and
       qhdok_udr.ucet_obd like '%2015.09%' and
       qhdok_udr.cis_zbozi_pracovisteadd like temptab.pracoviste       
  ) as hdmechanikpracoviste,
  (select sum(qhdok_udr.hdccenaval2)
     from qhdok_udr
       left join typdok on typdok.idtypdok = qhdok_udr.idtypdok
     where
       typdok.typ_dok = 'UDR' and
       qhdok_udr.podminky_text = 'UDRMECH' and
       qhdok_udr.ucet_obd like '%2015.09%'
  ) as hdmechanikcelkem,
  sum(temptab.mnZmetky) as mnZmetky,
  sum(temptab.mnTuk) as mnTuk,
  sum(temptab.mnKukurice) as mnKukurice,
  sum(temptab.mnFolie) as mnFolie,
  sum(temptab.mnozstvi) as mnozstvi,
  sum(temptab.mnZmetky) * 24.7 as hdZmetky,
  sum(temptab.mnTuk) * 30 as hdTuk,
  sum(temptab.mnKukurice) * 10 as hdKukurice,
  sum(temptab.mnFolie) * 130 as hdFolie,
  sum((temptab.mnZmetky * 24.7)+(temptab.mnTuk * 30)+(temptab.mnKukurice * 10)+(temptab.mnFolie * 130)) as hdCelkem,
  sum((temptab.mnZmetky * 24.7)+(temptab.mnTuk * 30)+(temptab.mnKukurice * 10)+(temptab.mnFolie * 130)) / isnull(nullif(sum(temptab.mnozstvi),0),1) as hdKs
from
(select
  qhdok.idhdok,
  qhdok.ucet_obd,
  qhdok.dtzdanitpln,
  qhdok.podminky_text,
  qhdok.hdmzda_naklad_smena,
  qhdok.hdodpis_naklad_smena,
  pracoviste = case
    when qhdok.podminky_text like 'KB%'  then 'MKB'
    when qhdok.podminky_text like '2UP%' then 'MUP'
    when qhdok.podminky_text like 'M3%'  then 'M3'
    when qhdok.podminky_text like 'PUK%' then 'PUK'
    when qhdok.podminky_text like 'M1%' then 'M1'
    when qhdok.podminky_text like 'M2%' then 'M2'   
    else ''
  end,
  qhdok.jmeno_uziv,
  qhdok.mnpracovniku,
  isnull((select sum(HDHDOKPOZNCISLO) from qhdokpozn where qhdokpozn.idhdok = qhdok.idhdok and qhdokpozn.KODTHDOKPOZN like 'VYRZMP'),0)  as mnZmetky,
  isnull((select sum(HDHDOKPOZNCISLO) from qhdokpozn where qhdokpozn.idhdok = qhdok.idhdok and qhdokpozn.KODTHDOKPOZN like 'VYRZMT'),0)  as mnTuk,
  isnull((select sum(HDHDOKPOZNCISLO) from qhdokpozn where qhdokpozn.idhdok = qhdok.idhdok and qhdokpozn.KODTHDOKPOZN like 'VYRZMK'),0)  as mnKukurice,
  isnull((select sum(HDHDOKPOZNCISLO) from qhdokpozn where qhdokpozn.idhdok = qhdok.idhdok and qhdokpozn.KODTHDOKPOZN like 'VYRZMF'),0)  as mnFolie,
  isnull((select top 1 cast(HDOKPOZNMEMO as varchar(max))  from qhdokpozn where qhdokpozn.idhdok = qhdok.idhdok and qhdokpozn.KODTHDOKPOZN like 'VYRPOZ'),'') as textpozn2,
  isnull((select sum(dbo.fn_UO_mnPocetvAltMJ(qsdok.idzbozi, null, null, 'KS', qsdok.mncelkempocet)) from qsdok where qsdok.idhdok = qhdok.idhdok and qsdok.kod_pohyb ='P30' and qsdok.mncelkempocet>0 and
                    (qsdok.slozka_ident not like 'pmic%') and charindex('MIX',qsdok.nazev_zbozi)=0 and qsdok.cis_zbozi not like 'PROSTOJ%' and qsdok.cis_zbozi != 'POPCORN' ),0) as mnozstvi
 from qhdok_smena qhdok
 where qhdok.typ_dok = 'SPU' and (qhdok.idhdok_vzor = 41875 or qhdok.idhdok_vzor = 239530) and qhdok.ucet_obd like  '%2015.09%' and qhdok.podminky_text like '%%%'+'%' and (qhdok.podminky_text like 'M3%' or qhdok.podminky_text like '2UP%' or qhdok.podminky_text like 'KB%' or qhdok.podminky_text like 'M1%' or qhdok.podminky_text like 'M2%')

-- qhdok.idhdok,qhdok.ucet_obd, qhdok.idhdok, qhdok.dtzdanitpln,qhdok.podminky_text, qhdok.hdmzda_naklad_smena, qhdok.hdodpis_naklad_smena, qhdok.jmeno_uziv, qhdok.textpozn2, qhdok.mnpracovniku
) temptab
group by  temptab.idhdok, temptab.ucet_obd, temptab.dtzdanitpln, temptab.pracoviste, substring (temptab.podminky_text, 4,2), temptab.jmeno_uziv, temptab.textpozn2, temptab.mnpracovniku, temptab.hdodpis_naklad_smena, temptab.hdmzda_naklad_smena
```

this is the example what i have and what i need:
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B143P.png)

Answer (score 0):

What to put in your GROUP BY clause should be easy to tell: "I want one result record per __________________". Let's say that you fill this gap with `temptab.idhdok, temptab.ucet_obd, temptab.dtzdanitpln`, then your GROUP BY clause is accordingly:

```
GROUP BY temptab.idhdok, temptab.ucet_obd, temptab.dtzdanitpln;
```

All other columns you use in your SELECT clause must get aggregated with SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, etc. You have already done so with `SUM(temptab.hdmzda_naklad_smena)`.

So when you remove `temptab.pracoviste` from your existing GROUP BY clause, you can no longer use this column itself, but only an aggregate of it, e.g. `MIN(temptab.pracoviste)`.

So for instance the line

```
qhdok_udr.cis_zbozi_pracovisteadd like temptab.pracoviste
```

would have to be

```
qhdok_udr.cis_zbozi_pracovisteadd like MIN(temptab.pracoviste)
```

then.

BTW: Why is this `like`? This makes no sense, as `pracoviste` contains no wildcards. It should simply be `=` instead of `like`.

One more thing:

```
count (temptab.idhdok) as pocet
count(temptab.pracoviste) as prac
```

`pracoviste` is never NULL, so it is the same as `count(*)`. Can `idhdok` ever be NULL? Otherwise it, too, would equal `count(*)`. Is this desired?

Comment: Thank you, I got the thing about aggregation of sum, avg, min, etc.. I changed my group by according to that, but still I have my results leaving the two rows that should be merged separated (in my example it should be these, that have the jmeno_uziv = "C" and "dtzdanitpln = 2015-09-11 00:00:00"  , I think that is because I have the temptab.idhdok in the Group by still.. Because every idhdok is unique, so it does not merge them together.. Now my grou by looks like this: group by temptab.idhdok, temptab.ucet_obd, temptab.dtzdanitpln

Comment: You are right. As you don't want separate rows for different `idhdok`, it is none of the columns you would put in the gap in "I want one result record per __________________" and must hence not be part of the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: great, now it works :) Thank you, still might come back tomorrow, if I will find something that needs a fix.